# Python not creating new file headers when it does not exist

Tags: python

I want to write a new CSV file with headers if it does not exist, and append row data to it. Not sure why the following code doesn't add the file headers? (Append works fine)

```py
import os
import csv

path = "test.csv"


with open(path, mode="a") as f:    
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        writer.writerow(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"])

    row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: maybe because if you open the file it must already exist and therefore `if not os.path.exists(path)` will never trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to move *if exists* test before opening the file. Opening the file in "a" mode will create the file if it does not already exist.

```python
import os
import csv

path = "test.csv"

exists = os.path.exists(path)
with open(path, mode="a") as f:    
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    if not exists:
        writer.writerow(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"])

    row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    writer.writerow(row)
```